# IE blocks pdf file save popup

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created savepdf.aspx which writes pdf file contents to response as attchment by following code

```
       Response.Clear();
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Sample.pdf");
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.BinaryWrite(transcriptFileBytes);
        Response.End();
```

When click on button of parent page savepdf.aspx opens as popup, which writes pdf file contens.

Now problem is popup just gets open and close immediatly without prompting for file save diaolog box.

But, when I hold Ctrl key while clicking on parent button, popup does appears and ask for file open save dialog box. This time works fine.

How to fix this behaviour through code?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change this behavior from the server - it's a client-side configuration for handling of disposition `attachment`, which you have set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Response.End() here please comment this line and close this popup window by using javascript.

I hope it will resolve you porblem...